Prove that the space of solutions to y'''-9y''+26y'-24y=0 has dimension 3.
So, I've seen proofs of this for a more general case, and those proofs sometimes involve abstract algebra, but I was wondering if, in this more specific, case, there is an easier proof (especially since the characteristic equation factors nicely). Of course it is easy to find 3 solutions, but how do we show that there are no other solutions that are linearly independent to these 3?

Why not just use the definition of linear independence?

Uniqueness says that two solutions with identical $y, y', y''$  at $x=0$  are identical. So, all are a sum of  a solution with $(1,0,0),$  one with $(0,1,0),$  and $(0,0,1)$

I guess the big thing is naming new variables $y_0 = y, y_1 = y', y_2 = y''$  and making a linear system. You haven't said what book you have or how far in.
